# How to pass params into timeit.timeit function Python

Tags: python-3.7, timeit

I have to test my function:

```
def change_min_and_max(array):
    some_code
```

And I need to use `timeit.timeit` for it. But I can't pass an array into my function:

```
import random
array = [random.randint(-1000, 1000) for _ in range(100)]
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('change_min_and_max(array)', number=100))
```

> name 'change_min_and_max' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that timeit executes the code in a seperate namespace and doesn't know about the function and array definitions. You can specify a namespace with the `globals` parameter. If you simply want to use the current namespace you can use the `globals()` function like this:

```
import random, timeit

def change_min_and_max(array):
    ...

array = [...]

timeit.timeit("change_min_and_max(array)", globals=globals())
```